# How to display pdf file in reader from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, pdf

Hello I am working in windows application "winforms" in this I have successfully save pdf file in database now I want to display that in adobe reader which i have been added from toolbox
what should I need to do, thats why I can able to view pdf in adobe reader.
I already try to display pdf file to reader but nothing display.

Here is my code:

```
{
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("select PDFFILE from help ;", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        byte[] img = (byte[])command1.ExecuteScalar();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
        string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(img);

        axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(s);
        con.Close();         
}
```

Comment: LoadFile takes file name and I don't see there any method that accepts a PDF content. How about saving content to temp file and pass temp file name to LoadFile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the adobe control only takes a filename, you will need to save the pdf as a file first. System.IO.Path will get you a temporary path. Using a guid will also prove useful for random names.

If you don't want that, you may use the `PdfiumViewer`, which is Googles `Pdfium` wrapped as a .NET control. Works fine, takes streams as load parameter and is easy to use. You can get both the PdfiumViewer and the required Pdfium-DLLs via NuGet. Plus, you won't be dependent on the installed adobe version any more.

Comment: Thank you @Otterprinz. I will try that. I will install Pdfium.Net.sdk.

Comment: THANK YOU @Otterprinz. I got it. My problem solve thankyou

Comment: Hello @Otterprinz . I got a problem in pdfviewer. It says Unable to load DLL 'pdfium.dll'. The specific module could not be found. I try to fix it but didnt work

Comment: Hey @Aopgatimam! You wrote, that you planned to install Pdfium.Net SDK, which i have no experience with. I'm using and recommmended PdfiumViewer by Peter van Ginkel. The PdfiumViewer package is just the wrapper, you still need the native pdfium.dll for it to work. There are NuGet packages for it, PdfiumViewer.Native.x86 and PdfiumViewer.Native.x64. Installing those will create x86/x64 subdirectories in your outpu folder and the PdfiumViewer will load the one that matches the current architecture.

Comment: thank you for your reply @Otterprinz pdfiumViewer is now working properly  thank you

Comment: can I ask another question? @Otterprinz?

Comment: I code for print button using printdialog and printdocument. I cant print but in  a single page only. I want to get multiple copies to print. I tried this code

Comment: I tried this code =  printDocument.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2; but this code is wrong